# java null pointer exception with object is declared already

Tags: java

I'm trying to park a plane at a gate in my array if the gate is vacant. If the gate is occupied, then I will park the plane at a vacant gate, as done in my else statement. When I run my tester, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException on the line of the if statement. I'm not sure why. Any advice is appreciated.

```
public void parkPlane(Plane plane){
    for (int i = 0; i < this.plane.length; ++i) {
        if(this.plane[i].equals(null)){ //java.lang.NullPointerException pointing to this line.
            plane.setGateNumber(i);
        }
        else{
            plane.setGateNumber(getVacantGate());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of the array before the if statement? Are there any `null` values in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is null, calling `equals` on it will raise an exception. Use `==` instead.

The problem is that if the object is null, then it is not initialized already (even if it was declared). Calling any method on `null` raises a `NullPointerException`. However, `==` compares where the objects are in memory; if they are stored in the same place, they are exactly the same object. If both objects are `null`, they are considered to both be stored in the same place (nowhere) so they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Passing `null` to `equals` must always return `false`:

> For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return false.
>
> ([documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)))

If you want to compare anything for `null` in Java, use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

This check `this.plane[i].equals(null)` makes no sense. If `this.plane[i]` is `null`, then you'll get the mentioned `NullPointerException`, because you're calling the method `equals` on a `null` reference.

Change it to:

```
if(this.plane[i] == null) {
    // ...
}
// ...
```